zorder is not working properly in multiple errorbar plots on the same figure
I am trying to create two line plots with errorbar using the primary and secondary y-axis on the same figure. I want to plot the errorbar line in such a way that it does not overlap the markers on the line plots. zorder is not working here properly. The errorbar corresponding to the secondary y-axis always overlaps the markers of the primary y-axis line plot but the reverse is not showing.
data = {
    'A': [439, 1263, 1631, 2059],
    'A-std': [255, 829, 1058, 1365],
    'B': [0.16, 0.39, 0.47, 0.58],
    'B-std': [0.11, 0.18, 0.19, 0.18]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.0,4.0))
ccn_plot = ax.errorbar(df.index, df[df.columns[0]], 
                       yerr=df[df.columns[1]], label='Blue', color= 'blue', 
                       linewidth=4.0, elinewidth=2.0, ls='solid', capsize =5.0, zorder = 0)
                       
ax1 = ax.twinx()                      
## Plotting AF data on the secondary y-axis
af_plot = ax1.errorbar(df.index, df[df.columns[2]], 
                       yerr=df[df.columns[3]], label = 'Red', color = 'red', 
                       linewidth = 4.0, elinewidth=2.0, ls='solid', capsize =5.0, zorder = 0)

ax.scatter(df.index, df[df.columns[0]], 
           marker='s', s=50, c = 'blue',
           edgecolors='black', 
           zorder=10)  

ax1.scatter(df.index, df[df.columns[2]], 
            marker='o', s=50, c = 'red',
            edgecolors='black', 
            zorder=10)

## Collect legend handles and labels from both axes
primary_handles, primary_labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels() # from primary y-axes
sec_handles, sec_labels = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels() # from secondary y-axe

## Combine handles and labels
all_handles = primary_handles + sec_handles
all_labels = primary_labels + sec_labels
ax.legend(all_handles, all_labels)
    
ax.set_ylabel('Blue')
ax1.set_ylabel('Red')


I do not understand why zorder is showing such strenge behaviour.  I want to plot the errorbar line in such a way that it does not overlap the markers on any of the line plots. Is there any way to plot the all the markers of the figure with higher zorder than lines? Any help is highly appriciated. Thanks in advance.

Is this example representative? The difference between values on the blue scale vs red scale is so significant that I wonder why they're both on the same plot.

@ jared Yes, the actual dataset is similar to the given data. And I don't understand why zorder is not working for the scatter plot with respect to my code.

I think the problem is that you have twin axes the 2 axes also have their z-order. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66139357/error-bars-in-matplotlib-display-over-other-curves
